# Removed Colon (:) From URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I saved a URL in a database like `https://ecstasybd.com/`

But when I use is this link in an anchor tag colon `:` after `https` get removed.

I tried this way

`<a href="//{{ $stall->about_link }}" target="_blank">About</a>`

Output is like `<a href="https//ecstasybd.com/" target="_blank">About</a>`

I don't know why colon after https is getting removed.

Comment: url stored in database properly?

Comment: Did you print `{{!! $stall->about_link !!}}` only this and observe ?

Comment: Been there, done that: did you actually store the colon in the database? Else you could try `{!! !!}` or `urlencode()`

Comment: @ArtemIlchenko yes url stored in database properly

Comment: @Loek tried. but not worked

Comment: Looks more like browser mangling. Have you verified with a different browser, or `wget`/`curl` if what you see as "output" is the actual source?

Comment: Try debugging the variable in your controller using `dd($stall->about_link);` right before returning the view.

Answer (score 0):

Try {!! !!} something like this

```
<a href="{!! $stall->about_link !!}" target="_blank">About</a>
```

remove `//`

Hope this help you

Comment: Might be more helpful to future users if you explained what `{{!!` does differently, and why it might help with the supposed url and observed output.

Comment: '{!! !!}' remove and decode all tags except data '{{ }}' & '{!! !!}' both will work same if you don't have tags also not remove any mark like ': ; , .' check your database and try to dd($stall->about_link); what result come out

Answer (score 0):

You can leave all characters in the string by [displaying unescaped data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade#displaying-data):

> ### Displaying Unescaped Data
>
> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlspecialchars function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not
>   want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:
>
> `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`

So for your example it would be this:

```
<a href="{!! $stall->about_link !!}" target="_blank">About</a>
```